# How to Return datatable from webservice on .Net 4.5 or .Net 4?

Tags: asp.net

// WCF Code

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable Results(int pid)
{
    Results Rs = new Results();
    Rs.PID = pid;

//Return DataTable
    return Rs.getResults();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you set the name for your `DataTable` or else it will not get serialized.

Edit: You can make use of `DataTable.TableName` property to set the name.

Comment: Thank you for Answer, How can i give the DataTable a name?

Comment: WCF would take of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i gave it a name and every thing is ok.